Mogul base 3 way only on 2nd and 3rd rotation of knob
I recently bought a new mogul 3-way base and new bulb. The first click of knob nothing happens and then the 2nd and 3rd click light is on, normal, and at same brightness. Tried 3 new bulbs all the same. Does the socket need to be replaced? Anything else to check.

Are you sure that the bulb is a 3-way bulb?

One of the contacts in the socket isn't making contact (or a filament is broken on the new bulb, but having tried 3 bulbs, it's probably the socket.)
Usually you can slightly bend the contact up to correct the issue, but if not, new socket would be needed. Its generally the middle-ring contact. Do be sure the lamp cord is disconnected or the breaker is off before adjusting.
